# x3650 M5 / Single Copy Session Limit under Windows 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, storage, network-attached-storage, lenovo

Scenario:

```
- System x3650 M5 / MT: 88718 [With all latest hardware updates]
- Core CPU x 1 / 16 GB Ram 300 GB x 2
- Raid-1 for OS [C: Drive]
- 1.8TB x 8 Disks RAID-10 for Data [ 2 partitions / E: & F: drive]  
- OS: Windows 2012 R2 64bit / Windows Updated
```

Problem:

When I start 1st copy session from local to local storage, it works fine, but when I start 2nd copy session, 1st copying progress halts and 2nd session continue to copy files , Once 2nd session finishes its copying, then 1st gets auto resume. This is the problem that all copy sessions are not working simultaneously.

[image]

Comment: Why is this a problem? I'd assume Windows knows what it's doing (in this case), as your transfer speed is already at over 800MB/s. What benefit do you expect by copying multiple files concurrently?

Comment: in the screen its showing 800MB dueto the fact that I copied files for the server to the directly attached NAS which have 2 G nics with load balancing, & the NAS have ssd cache disk also , so initially it shows the 800MB but after few seconds it drops back under 200 MB

Comment: This isn't local to local storage, then. You have to consider limitations of the NICs, controller in the NAS, load balancing provider (driver in this case), etc.

Comment: How about the 2 simultaneous copies from local to local? It looks like that opened TCP socket to NAS device is more preferred than a local device. How exactly NAS device is connected (iSCSI, SMB)? 
Robocopy is the alternative way since it is multi-thread software which for sure will allow you to copy data in parallel.